# Keep object oriented towards a point while it's animated along a path

Tags: iphone, cocoa, cocoa-touch, animation, caanimation

I'm trying to animate an object along a path...while it's moving it should continue to "point" towards another object (or CGPoint). What should I be looking for in the framework (Cocoa-Touch) to accomplish this? Maybe something in `CAShapeLayer`? Though I think that's more for animating the path itself...  It's not jumping out at me...

Comment: I believe you're looking for the "bearing" between two points. Here's [a good starting point](https://web.archive.org/web/20171219235009/http://mathforum.org/library/drmath/view/55417.html) to get you going.